# How to properly download stocks data in python

Tags: python, pandas, web, pandas-datareader

I have been trying to extract stock prices using pandas_datareader. data, but
I kept receiving an error message.

I have checked other threads relating to this problem and, I have tried downloading data reader using conda install DataReader and also tried pip install DataReader.

```
import pandas as pd

 import datetime

from pandas import Series,DataFrame

import pandas_datareader.data as web

pandas_datareader.__version__

'0.6.0'

start=datetime.datetime(2009,1,1)

end=datetime.datetime(2019,1,1)

df=web.DataReader( 'AT&T Inc T',start,end)

df.head()
```

My expected result should be a data frame with all the features and rows of the stock.

Below is the error message I got:
Please, how do I fix this problem?

Thanks.

```
<ipython-input-45-d75bedd6b2dd> in <module>


      1 start=datetime.datetime(2009,1,1)

      2 end=datetime.datetime(2019,1,1)

----> 3 df=web.DataReader( 'AT&T Inc T',start,end)

      4 df.head()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py in DataReader(name,

 data_source, start, end, retry_count, pause, session, access_key)

    456     else:

    457         msg = "data_source=%r is not implemented" % data_source

--> 458         raise NotImplementedError(msg)
    459 
    460 

NotImplementedError: data_source=datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 1, 0, 0) is not implemented
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked:

```
import pandas as pd

import datetime

from pandas import Series,DataFrame

import pandas_datareader
import pandas_datareader.data as web

pandas_datareader.__version__

start=datetime.datetime(2009,1,1)

end=datetime.datetime(2019,1,1)

df=web.DataReader( 'T', "yahoo", start,end)

print(df.head())
```

The data log is as the follows:

```
                 High        Low    ...          Volume  Adj Close
Date                                ...                           
2009-01-02  29.459999  28.430000    ...      21879800.0  16.438549
2009-01-05  28.889999  28.059999    ...      32414700.0  15.885386
2009-01-06  28.700001  28.000000    ...      28746100.0  15.812749
2009-01-07  27.650000  27.000000    ...      30532700.0  15.427205
2009-01-08  27.350000  26.820000    ...      21431200.0  15.410195

[5 rows x 6 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it.

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
import datetime as dt

start = '2019-6-20'
end = '2019-7-20'

tickers = ['CSCO',
'AXP',
'HD',
'PG']

thelen = len(tickers)

price_data = []
for ticker in tickers:
    prices = wb.DataReader(ticker, start = start, end = end, data_source='yahoo')[['Adj Close']]
    price_data.append(prices.assign(ticker=ticker)[['ticker', 'Adj Close']])

df = pd.concat(price_data)
df.dtypes
df.head()
df.shape

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)

df = df.reset_index()
df = df.set_index('Date')
table = df.pivot(columns='ticker')
# By specifying col[1] in below list comprehension
# You can select the stock names under multi-level column
table.columns = [col[1] for col in table.columns]
table.head()
```

Result:

```
                   AXP       CSCO          HD          PG
Date                                                     
2019-06-20  124.530563  57.049965  211.250000  111.021019
2019-06-21  124.341156  56.672348  209.389999  110.484497
2019-06-24  123.752991  56.821407  205.500000  111.607231
2019-06-25  122.776054  55.728306  204.740005  111.001152
2019-06-26  123.204704  56.245041  206.419998  109.023956
```